# How can select an area of the image using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, mouseevent

i want to select an area of the image (which having some text).
I am using following steps-
Click on the image and hold >> move mouse >> release
Its clicking on the image but not selected the area of the image.
Please let me know how can i do this. Please find attached image for more details

i used following code:

```
WebElement window1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cropper-drag-box"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(window1, 180, 120).clickAndHold().build().perform();   
action.moveByOffset(window1, 220, 160).release().build().perform();

Another one code:
WebElement window1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cropper-drag-box"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(window1, 180, 120).clickAndHold().build().perform();   
action.moveToElement(window1, 220, 160).release().build().perform();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPzJe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic code to select (highlight) the element area with mouse.

*Note: Replace `element` with `window1` in your case.*

**Java:**

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element, 1, 1).clickAndHold().moveToElement(element, element.getSize().width-1, 1).release().perform();
```

**C#:**

```
new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(element, 1, 1).ClickAndHold().MoveToElement(element, element.Size.Width-1, 1).Release().Perform();
```

**Python**

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 1, 1).click_and_hold().move_to_element_with_offset(element, element.rect['width']-1, 1).release().perform();Add
```